# Realtime Bake to UV using touch designer

Tags: projection, uv-mapping

I want to to bake the 3d video to the flatten uv of the screen like this video tutorial https://youtu.be/xK3q641dd2c?t=494

- I have the rendered content of mp4 from the camera angle of sweet spot
- The screen fbx with uv in a square grid

I want to know how can i bake he rendered content to the screen which is a curved one like the above video

Tried blender using uv project on the curved display then flattening the curved display which is time consuming so i want a realtime solution which is faster as my videos are long